# Why doesn't my repeating linear gradient work in Safari even after trying -webkit-linear-gradient? It works perfectly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, safari, linear-gradients

Refer to this codepen. Even the codepen code doesn't work in Safari but works in Chrome.

https://codepen.io/srbsingh3/pen/bGpgQoY

```css
div {

height: 400px;
margin-left: 200px;
background: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 0 3px, transparent 3px 8px) 0/1px no-repeat,
linear-gradient(to bottom, #74ddb1 0 19px, transparent 19px 133px, #74ddb1 133px 152px, transparent 152px 100%) 0/1px no-repeat;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `rgb` but pass parameters for `rgba`; you set your background size to 1px so it's tiny.

Specifying `rgba` and playing with position and size makes backgrounds in your pen visible in Safari on iOS.

Comment: I tried it but doesn't work for me. Did it work for you?

Comment: After following steps I outlined in my answer I see stripey backgrounds in Safari on macOS and iOS